# macOS Sierra: Localhost will not connect

Tags: macos, server, localhost, macos-sierra

I just updated to Sierra from El Capitan. When I went to continue my work on my localhost, which happens to be on my Mac, it stopped working. When I go to `http://localhost/` 1st it says "It works", when I reload the page, it says "This site can’t be reached", the same when I go to `localhost/~matthew`. It does not list all the files and folders like it should. Does anybody know why or have had a similar problem? Any way to fix it? I've checked Terminal and localhost is in fact running.

I've already tried using `localhost/~matthew/`, `http://localhost/~matthew/` and `[actual ip address]/~matthew/`. None of these work. 
The server is apache. The `Sites` folder is already in place under `Users/Matthew/`.

[image: Localhost on macOS Sierra won't work]

Comment: Hi Matthew, I am facing the same problem ... Do you mind to let us know if you found any solution for this?

Comment: I've looked online and even asked a college classmate. I've called Apple and they didn't know anything about it. So solution so far.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. Please post this in a more appropriate place.

Comment: And what place would that be?

Comment: Please stop adding the apple tag. Please read its description. It clearly states "DO NOT USE". And please do not add an update to your question just to say you haven't found a solution yet. That doesn't add anything to your question.

Comment: Try posting at http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MatthewCampbell, I used below tutorial last week and localhost started running. Give it a try and let us know if the issue is solved: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/

Answer (score 0):

If you uncommened loading php5_module in the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf, DO NOT COMMENT OUT. Make sure this line commented (which means, # has to be prefixed)

 `#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

Also, when you change httpd.conf file, make sure to execute `sudo apachectl restart`